# What are these white spots on my Purslane leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, succulents

I am growing [Purslane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portulaca_oleracea) as vegetables, however I noticed some white spots on the leaves.  I used agriculture pesticides for aphids, whitefly and so on but nothing changed.

Do you think these white dots are a fungal infection? If so what pesticide is recommended for it?

I am attaching photos for the infected purslane, hoping you can figure out what that is.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Comment: Do you grow purslane to eat? That's a lot of purslane. It just grows wild here.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is they might be patches of eggs. I say patches of eggs because in picture #2 there is some that are just little dots ad the others seem very much the size. There is a VERY little red bug in my area that does that. But I have no idea of what the name is. My other guess is it can be a fungus. Again not knowing what it could be.

But play it safe and remove all the leaves that have that stuff on them. It does not look harmful but why not be safe, right?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,by the way these white dots looks like soft powder and can be removed.

Comment: Then I would lean towards eggs.

Comment: I am leaning more towards a scale, another sucking insect.  Cut those leaves off for sure and keep an eye out.  Very easy to control.  When you rub or scrape those spots off, is there a 'sucked up spot'?  Don't know how else to ask that...could you rub some off and take a picture...does it feel like a 'body' or is it uniformly bits of 'powder'?  Is it squishy?  Scale moves very slowly leaving behind 'sucked up spots'...

Comment: @stormy
if i scrap those white spots there is something like jelly or as you mentioned "body","sucked up spot".i made some research and concluded that "boisduval scale" is it right ? i noticed some white insects on the leaves ,wishing you help me more in this issue.what treatment is supposed to use for. look at the attached photos in the first post last image

Comment: This site is on boisduval scale, there is lots of information here to help you. And at the bottom they have 3 different treatments. Hope this helps you out... http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/orn/scales/boisduval_scale.htm

Comment: @user3142694 Is there anything on the underside of the leaf, corresponding with the white deposits on top? Or anything underneath that shouldn't be there?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I let the purslane grow as a ground cover under my vegetable garden because I eat it too. I think the dots are leafminer eggs. If you see a lot of tiny flies in your garden that might be the problem. They lay their eggs on the leaves of some plants (they love the soft leaves of lettuce, spinach and kale). When the eggs hatch the larvae "tunnel" through the leaf and make a white wavy pattern. If you see leaves on other plants with that pattern, you probably have leafminer flies too. 
http://www.gerbera.org/diseases/leaf-miner/ 
http://www.planetnatural.com/pest-problem-solver/houseplant-pests/leafminer-control/

Comment: I think it is not leafminer,this is what i think the symptoms of "boisduval scale" google it and take a look.thank you

Comment: @user3142694 If they're leaf miners, you should find out pretty soon if you don't remove them, but I wouldn't wait if you want to get rid of them. I know purslane can get leaf miners; it's the only pest I've ever seen on mine, but it could be scale insects I suppose; it looks like it may be. Are they a known pest for purslane? You can answer your own question and accept it as the answer if you know it (don't do it in the question itself, though).

Answer (score -1):

White Rust, seemingly...

https://www.gardenguides.com/122680-portulaca-diseases.html

<30 character gap filler>

Comment: This is a link-only answer, which is not helpful : just imagine that the page you link to goes down. What information would remain? None! This goes against the basic principle of creating a knowledge base instead of posting an answer that’s useful for just one asker. So linking is fine, but please paraphrase the core information, in case of link rot. Hint: if the system demands more text, is usually trying to help you to create a better post, so instead of a filler, add *useful information*!